# How to change a value in local storage

Tags: javascript

I am saving on the local storage this item on the key `perfil`.

```
[{"inscricao":{"nome":"Duarte","passe":"1234","email":"abcd@abcd.com"},"estatisticas":{"totalJogos":0,"totalTempo":0}}]
```

My question is how do I change the field `totalJogos` to 1 for example. I tried doing this...

```
function get_localstorage(){
  let x = localStorage.getItem("perfil")
  return JSON.parse(x)
}

get_localstorage()[0]["estatisticas"]["totalJogos"] = 1;
```

...but it doesn't change anything. How can I change it ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it again after changing it:

```
function get_localstorage(){
  let x = localStorage.getItem("perfil")
  return JSON.parse(x)
}

const newValue = get_localstorage();
newValue[0]["estatisticas"]["totalJogos"] = 1;

localStorage.setItem("perfil", JSON.stringify(newValue));
```